# Random 4 Image into 4 Different Button for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Here is my code:

```
-(void)RandomButtonImage {

    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Character_1_1.png",@"Character_1_2.png",@"Character_2_1.png",@"Character_2_2.png" nil];

    NSArray *Buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:AnsButton1,AnsButton2,AnsButton3,AnsButton4, nil];

    for (UIButton *btn in Buttons) {
        int randomIndex = random() % images.count;
        UIImage *img = [images objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
        [btn setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [images removeObjectsAtIndexes:randomIndex];
    }
}
```

I tried looking at other post, however my coding is exactly the same.

Comment: And... what do you want?

Comment: My coding isn't working, the first error is the last line:[images removeObjectsAtIndexes:randomIndex];Implicit Conversion of 'int' to 'NSindexset' is disallowed with ARC. Even if i remove the last line. There still error.

Comment: Isn't working but please explain what you're trying to achieve. We're not thought-readers, we need to know what you want to achieve, what you're seeing instead, and what you've tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take some object in NSArray and put it randomly in labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557077/take-some-object-in-nsarray-and-put-it-randomly-in-labels)

Comment: i need to display 4 image random in 4 different button

Comment: Then please *edit* your question to provide as much details as possible. And please read Stack Overflow's FAQ on asking, too. Apart from that, welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`images` is an array of `NSString`, not an array of `UIImage`.

Try this:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however it's still does not work

Comment: See my other answer. Two problems, two answers!

Answer (score 0):

`removeObjectsAtIndexes` wants a `NSIndexSet`, not a single integer :

Either use `[images removeObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];`

or `[images removeObjectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:randomIndex]];`